# Need to extend IF formula to include conditions in multiple cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Good afternoon world,

I am trying to use IF formulas to include conditions in multiple cells for determining output. So far, I have gotten the following formula to begin behaving the way I want:

```
=IF(D2="","Engagement",IF(D2<TODAY(),"Stabilization",""))
```

However I'd like to include all of the following additional conditions:

- If E2 is blank, then F2="Engagement" (DONE)
- If E2 is before TODAY, then F2="Stabilization" (DONE)
- If D2 is blank, then F2="Intake"
- If C2="Check-In", then F2="Maintenance"

(See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk/edit?usp=sharing for reference)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in E2. You can move the if statements around to get them in your priority/goes first.

```
=IF(D2="","Engagement",
IF(AND(D2<TODAY(),C2>TODAY()-DATE(0,7,0)),"Maintenance",
IF(C2="","Intake",
IF(D2<TODAY(),"Engagement",""))))
```

Comment: That's awesome, but I am ending up with some unwanted blanks. I've changed something from my original post and have corrected it above.

Comment: @minky_boodle where does "Stabilization" come in? Should it be that instead of the blanks you get. If so replace that in for the final `""` in my formula?

Comment: got it! Thank you!

Comment: @minky_boodle was replacing the "" with "Stabilization"? And you are welcome

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.